# Audacity mount issue in Jelllyfish

Tags: mount, snap, gtk, audacity, yaru

Attempting to install audacity on Jammy Jellyfish via snap due to some previous issues with using ppa. I refreshed the snap, then purged and reinstalled audacity. However, the program does not run, seeming due to a name/path issue I cannot parse. Please see below.

```
cc@Cleo:~$ sudo snap remove --purge audacity
[sudo] password for cc: 
audacity removed

cc@Cleo:~$ audacity
bash: /snap/bin/audacity: No such file or directory

cc@Cleo:~$ sudo snap install audacity
audacity 3.1.3 from Daniel Llewellyn (diddledani✪) installed

cc@Cleo:~$ audacity
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Materia-compact /snap/audacity/1032/data-dir/themes/Materia-compact none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Materia-compact" because it would affect the host in "/snap"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Materia-dark-compact /snap/audacity/1032/data-dir/themes/Materia-dark-compact none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Materia-dark-compact" because it would affect the host in "/snap"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Yaru-MATE-dark /snap/audacity/1032/data-dir/themes/Yaru-MATE-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot use "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Yaru-MATE-dark" as bind-mount source: not a directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Yaru-MATE-light /snap/audacity/1032/data-dir/themes/Yaru-MATE-light none bind,ro 0 0): cannot use "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/gtk2/Yaru-MATE-light" as bind-mount source: not a directory
Warning: GTK2 does not support Wayland!
^C

cc@Cleo:~$ sudo audacity:
```

> > mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > realpath: '': No such file or directory
> > Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice...
> > Testing for ALSA permissions...
> > Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
> > Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

> > (yad:166320): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:31:22.641: cannot open display: :0
> > ...use PulseAudio this time and ask next time.

Comment: `sudo audacity mkdir:`  what is the idea of doing that?  Why do you have GTK-2?

Comment: I can clean that up, the actual command was sudo audacity. Also, I don't know where GTK-2 came from, I would have thought it was part of the ubuntu distro

Comment: never execute an application using root  `sudo audacity`  as it may write local config setting files as root which may generate permission errors when running as normal user later ...  you have some local issue as my `audacity` install using snap runs just fine and yet on launch it shows same startup messages as you show which I just ignore as application runs OK